# How to create POJO from a given XML using JAXB

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb

I am Stuck while unmarshel XML into POJO class using JAXB . based on input XML I can not able to generate perfect POJO class because of that unable to unmarshel XML . so can any one suggest what POJO is required based on Input XML 
Input XML :

```
<Main>
<Response>
<DataStatus>Request OK.  Found 1 records.</DataStatus>
<List numberOfRows='277' pageIndex='1' pageSize='30000' totalNumberOfEntries='277'>
<DataStatus>
  <Id>Mar09</Id>
  <Name>0251</Name>
  <Status>W</Status>
  <StartDate>2009-02-25</StartDate>
  <EndDate>2009-05-20</EndDate>
  <ImpDelivered>0</ImpDelivered>
  <ClicksDelivered>0</ClicksDelivered>
  <WhenModified>2009-03-12 14:29:48</WhenModified>
 </DataStatus>
 </List>
 </Response>
  </Main>
```

POJO:

```
public class DataStatus {

private String id;
private String name;
private String status;
private String startDate;
private String endDate;
private String impDelivered;
private String clicksDelivered;
private String whenModified;

//setter and & getters

}
```

thanks for help in advance

Comment: The character cases don't correspond, you'll have to use the jaxb annotations and explicitly set the name binding.

Comment: @MouseEvent can you Please suggest what I am  missing because new in jaxb . thanks

Comment: Take a look at the `XmlElement` annotation in the JavaDoc

Comment: In computer world 'Id' and 'id' are completely distinct, that is what causes problems. Either match the cases or use annotations. In any case you'll have to annotate the pojo class with 'XmlRootElement'.

Answer (score 1):

You are saying

> I can not able to generate perfect POJO class

Are you realy want to generate class or instace of class *POJO*? In case of unmarshaling XML to java instance using JAXB you have to use annotation for class as @MouseEvent noticed. [Here](http://www.techferry.com/articles/jaxb-annotations.html) you can find explanation. For field it is same in case name of class attribute is not named same as xml tag.

In case of generating class it is more difficult but possible.